# Blender using sculp mode change show in sculp and object not showing in edit

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am playing with adding eyebrows. I used the sculp tool and drew a eyebrow, but when I go to edit mode to move the eyebrows the  image is flat.

Sculpt mode;[image]

Object mode
[image]

Edit mode ( no eyebrow , image flat
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a *Multires* modifier, it fakes a higher resolution mesh, and if you sculpt it won't affect the mesh itself.

If you need to change the mesh for real, disable *Multires* and activate *Dyntopo*.

If you want to keep a low-resolution mesh and just want to bake the normals of the sculpt you've made, you can keep the *Multires*, and at the end bake on the same object, or you can duplicate your object, use *Dyntopo* on one version, then bake this *Dyntopo* version on the other one.

But maybe you can simply create another mesh for the eyebrows?